# createUserWithEmailAndPassword error whit Reactive forms

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I used ngModel before and everything was fine. Now I am using Reactive form to create a user in Firebase.

My question is how can I access the values of each field, since it marks me the following error: `createUserWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument" email "must be a valid string`

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="nuevoUsuario()" novalidate>        
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>E-mail</mat-label>
    <input type="email" matInput placeholder="Ingresa tu E-mail" formControlName="email">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Contraseña</mat-label>
    <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Genera tu contraseña" formControlName="password">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block mt-3" [disabled]="!forma.valid" >Crear cuenta <i class="fas fa-user-plus ml-2"></i></button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```
email: any;
password: string;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, public router: Router, public authService: FirebaseService) {  
this.forma = fb.group ({
  email: [ 'xxx@xxx.com', [Validators.required, Validators.email] ],
  password: [ 'xxx', Validators.required ],
})
}

nuevoUsuario() {
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
  .then(userData => {
    userData.sendEmailVerification();
    this.router.navigate(['/ingresar']);
    console.log(userData)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by accessing in this way:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.forma.value.email, this.forma.value.password)
```